# Comparison between GWT and Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, gwt, spring-mvc

I was wondering if someone who was experienced in both technologies could give an objective comparison between the two, assuming you were building a complex web application that would be both very rich in on the server and in the browser.

One problem with the older paradigm, for me, is testability of the Spring MVC layer. I find that there's a lot of bugs that can creep into your application due to untestable annotations. This model also slows development cycles because you have to restart the server to make changes to the annotations/controller code... which is something I personally find very annoying.

I also don't want to deal with the complexity of javascript. Working with and testing an application all in Java sounds appealing to me. I don't really want to master another language, and learn all of its quirks, weird design decisions, idiosyncracies and the full history of browser incompatibilities.

So for a complex application, would GWT offer a superior approach? Are there any serious limitations to this approach over Spring MVC, which would probably be more flexible although harder to work with? Are there any gotchas and road blocks that are common for building complex applications?

I would really appreciate a comparison between the two. Please keep in mind that I have no experience with GWT, but about 10+ years experience with Spring. Thank you!

Comment: When considering GWT, check if the performance is acceptable for you.

Answer (score 4):

The truth is that also GWT has a learning curve and also at least at the time I looked at it, two years ago, you're not doing much with the basic controls, you need external libraries and that means more learning.

After trying to learn GWT without much success, I opted for a webservice plus either jQuery or ExtJS, which also gives a very clean separation of the roles. I sat down and learnt JavaScript, it wasn't easy but it was immensely more fun than using GWT.

As for browser compatibility, once you use a modern library, you'll have very few of them. My code works in all browsers without too many problems, including IE 6. Also when I am too busy, I write the services only and outsource the JavaScript interface part, which allows increased productivity.

Anyway, this is fairly subjective, another person fluent with GWT, can have an opposite point of view of mine. I will anyway reject the following reasons:

- **ease of debugging**. Not true anymore: it's very easy to debug JavaScript with FireBug, plus there won't be any business logic in JavaScript, only services call and display.
- **browser compatibility**. There are very few quirks to remember, the most common one is that IE doesn't accept trailing commas in lists, which is anyway not in the standard, but Firefox tolerates them. Any modern JavaScript library will take care of compatibility for you.
- **Speed**. To start with I will state that JavaScript is very fast for any reasonable computation within the browser. What is slower is DOM manipulation and of course anything involving the network, like AJAX calls. Your page will perform just right if you don't do design mistakes, like stuffing too many things or other problems that can arise when adding many elements directly to the DOM, instead of building your structure and then attaching it all at once.

As far as I can think now, the only valid reason is, *I already know Java, I don't want to study another language*.

As for your comment on Spring MVC. I am using Spring MVC and I don't feel the pain of restarting the server. The whole point of Spring is that everything should be easy to work with outside the container! In the Spring controllers I've very minimal code that just call the underlying services. What I need to unit test well are the services.

The controllers have very few code to test, I could just call them and test them within JUnit, but, at least for now, my approach is having a simple external test done through a web page with jQuery calls that check their response (it's not unit test, it's an integration test, but I feel there is a very little value to unit test a controller, if it's written properly).

Comment: I also test my Controllers, so maybe I should have been more clear. It is not possible to unit test your controllers' annotations in a unit test. For example, if you forget to add @PathVariable to a method parameter, your unit test will still pass. Also, if you misname or misspell a request mapping, you need to restart the server. Obviously the annoyance of this is going to vary between person to person, but I want to be able to test as much of this stuff as possible before I even start tomcat to test out the views. Also, the Spring Container/Hibernate is very slow to start up for big apps.

Comment: I get your extra explanation. However GWT is not a replacement for Spring, so the problems you've outlined would be still there in a Spring + GWT setup. For the rest of my answer, it's my opinion, of course.

Comment: If that's the case, then I think I'm pretty much done with writing web applications then. I just don't enjoy javascript. The basic API offered in all browsers is quite bad, and I find myself relying on 4-6 essential libraries (above jquery and the jquery plugins) just to get the basic programming api. There are so many javascript coding styles, naming conventions, etc. that I think are too much cognitive load for someone that hasn't been using it for years. It's just unfortunate really. Also, I've tried various unit testing methods and none of them met my satisfaction. It's just unfortunate.

Comment: One thing that would make Spring MVC more enjoyable is for the IDE or for the design to prevent you from even starting tomcat if the annotations are wrong, like a compile error, or something like that. Programming against the browser, or to Javascript is harder than it should be. It's much more complicated than simply calling into the lower below, that's for damn sure. The best unit testing framework was JsTestDriver, but it was buggy and even reported 0 failures when there was actually tests failing sometimes. Other times it just locked up, and forced you to reopen your ide and browsers :(

Comment: @egervari: It is not so difficult to UnitTest your controllers together with annotations: Just load the Spring context and feed the mock HTTP request.

Comment: @dma_k: Oh, I didn't even know that this existed. This still doesn't deal with the javascript problem. Is it just me, or am I the only one that thinks writing applications based on 'string' json variables and http request parameters is really quite bad? If any of these names need to change, you need to change the tests, the controller, the javascript, and maybe even the id/class names in the html and the css too. It's endless work. The decoupling aspects to web programming, I think, are stupid. If this were all done in one platform/language, it would be enormously simpler. Or am I just insane?

Comment: I mean, with Java code, at least a class or method name is locked-in, and IDE refactoring support is good enough to know the entire code graph for it. It knows where it's being used. But once you throw strings, html and javascript into the mix, the IDE is a lot less useful - and can even create a ton of errors. No IDE that I know of deals with Javascript well. I don't even think it's possible. I just see this as extremely fragile, and it also means I need to keep track of all of these little details whenever I change the name of something... and who knows if I will get them all with tests?

Comment: I guess I just find that humans understand all of these relationships but computers don't. In a complex system, it is extremely difficult and even stressful to keep track of them all. It is a common source of bugs to fix 100 references to something that has changed, only to miss 1 or 2 of them. This doesn't happen when you refactor a Java method that's used in java code 100 times - it gets all 100. I guess I want to be spending my time programming new features, not tracking down string references to ad nauseum. It's just not fun. Maybe I am done with web programming. Maybe that's it.

Comment: @egervari, seems that you should look into GWT then, good luck. I might also pick it up again in the future.

Answer (score 4):

I am using GWT for more than a year now in a complex project (200 KLOC for the whole project), and I recommend you to give GWT a try.

In my opinion GWT is quite easy to learn, there are really good [tutorials](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuide.html) about how one should use this technology.

The advantage of using GWT is that one can build nice, fast, maintainable web apps, without knowing very little about browsers or javascript. You can also debug your client side code with a Java debugger and in complex apps this is huge.

Although GWT offers the possibility to properly unit test the client side code, this requires a good understanding of GWT's MVP paradigm and careful planning. If you mess up your code (which is not that hard, because GWT gives you total freedom) then you are going to end up losing this feature, but this is your fault, not GWT's.

Answer (score 1):

It took me a couple of months to learn Spring well enough to create fairly basice MVC apps.  It took me about a month to master GWT.  (It could be that it was easier because I had already worked with Android for three years and it works similar.  It even has the exact same unobvious solutions to some of its problems.)  So for me, GWT was definitely much easier to learn than Spring.